# datatables warning with valid data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to initialize a datatable object using the following code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.queued_auto_responders', function (event) {
  // queued_ids from the clicked row
  var queued_ids = $(this).attr('data-queued-ids').split(',');

  // Set the respective controls' values
  $.get("assets/php/get_queued_responders.php", {queued_ids: queued_ids})
    .done(function(n) {
      var table_queued_responders = $('#queued_auto_responders').DataTable({
        data: n,
        columns: [
          { data: 'send_date', title: 'Send Date'},
          { data: 'title', title: 'Title' },
          { data: 'markup', title: 'Action', createdCell:
            function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
              $(td).html(cellData);
            }
          }
        ]
      });
    })
    .fail(function(n) {
      console.log(n.responseText);
    });
});
```

and the data returned is the following JSON as verified by Network > XHR > [file] > Response:

```
[
  {
    "send_date": "2019-01-17",
    "title": "...",
    "markup": "<a type=\"button\" class=\"d-block text-center text-danger\" href=\"assets/php/stop_queued_responder.php?queue_id=71\">Stop from Sending</a>"
  },
  {
    "send_date": "2018-06-01",
    "title": "...",
    "markup": "<a type=\"button\" class=\"d-block text-center text-danger\" href=\"assets/php/stop_queued_responder.php?queue_id=72\">Stop from Sending</a>"
  },
  {
    "send_date": "2018-06-11",
    "title": "...",
    "markup": "<a type=\"button\" class=\"d-block text-center text-danger\" href=\"assets/php/stop_queued_responder.php?queue_id=73\">Stop from Sending</a>"
  }
]
```

The error that is returned is the following:

> DataTables warning: table id=queued_auto_responders - Requested unknown parameter 'send_date' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Whenever I follow the URL in the error message it points to the **Parameter is a String** category which states that the error is usually because:

- The data property specified doesn't exist (a typo or a gap in data)
- The value of the property specified is null

but as you can tell from the data returned, my data does meet either of those two conditions. I also verified that the returned data matches the format of the data for the **Object** category.

So why am I receiving that error?

**UPDATE**

This is the markup of the table that I'm attempting to initialize:

```
<table class="table" id="queued_auto_responders">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And I am using DataTables 1.10.16.

Comment: Please, add the html markup of the table, i.e, the element with ID **queued_auto_responders**. Also, what version of DataTables plugin you are using?

Comment: @D.Smania - take a look at my update.

Comment: i will try first with a more basic example, one column, and more debugging. I will put an answer with this code so we can have more info of whats going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try next changes (degraded to a more basic sample):

**HTML MARKUP**

```
<table class="table" id="queued_auto_responders">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Send Date</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".queued_auto_responders").on('click', function(event)
    {
        // queued_ids from the clicked row
        var queued_ids = $(this).attr('data-queued-ids').split(',');

        // Set the respective controls' values.
        $.getJSON("assets/php/get_queued_responders.php", {queued_ids: queued_ids})
        .done(function(n)
        {
            console.log("Received data: ");
            console.log("Received type of data: " + typeof(n));
            console.log(n);

            var table_queued_responders = $('#queued_auto_responders').DataTable({
                data: n,
                columns: [
                    {data: 'send_date'}
                ]
            });
        })
        .fail(function(n)
        {
            console.log(n.responseText);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I receive the same warning and the text in my console is "Received Data" followed by the JSON that I posted in my OP.

Comment: Ok, add `dataType: "json"` to `$.get()` and on the php side return the response like this: `echo json_encode($response);`. I will update my code for the first improvement.

Comment: I changed the method from `$.get` to `$.getJSON` and this time it did not produce the warning. The console logged an array instead of a String this time. But the results did not show in the HTML.

Comment: Thats a first fix, the result have to be a JSON object, not a string. Now we have to see why table is not filling...

Comment: The table not filling was my fault, I had some CSS hiding the `<div>` that held the table. So the problem was with the result of `$.get` returning a String instead of JSON. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Ok, read next example of how to fill the table: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html. I will made changes to match that.